# JavaFX ListView selection

Tags: java, javafx

I am using JavaFX and I created a custom layout for my `ListView`. Everything is working fine except one thing which is a nitpick to be honest but it's annoying me and I don't think it's a good experience for the user.
The issue is whenever I click on an item (the custom layout) the list refreshes and the items have this weird flash.
I thought maybe the CSS styling that I am using is the thing that's causing this but I really don't know so I'll just put the CSS code here:

```
ListView{
    -fx-background-color: rgb(252, 252, 252);
    -fx-background-radius: 15px;
}
.list-view .list-cell:filled:selected {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(206, 9, 90, 0);
}

.list-view .scroll-bar:vertical {
    -fx-opacity: 100%;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.list-view .scroll-bar:horizontal {
    -fx-opacity: 0%;
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.list-view .scroll-bar:horizontal .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: #000000;
}
.list-view .scroll-bar:vertical .thumb {
    -fx-background-color: #000000;
}
.list-view .list-cell:filled {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(245, 244, 244, 0);
    -fx-fill: #000000;
}
.list-view .list-cell {
    -fx-background-color: rgba(238, 8, 8, 0);
}
```

The look that I want is just the layout without the `ListView` selection because in the context of this the default `ListView` selection is not really needed, instead selection is handled within the layout with a check-box.

For a visual representation this is the list item layout:
[image: CUSTOM LAYOUT]

The code for the list-cell:

```
    public class Available_Groups_cell extends ListCell<Available_group> {
    private FXMLLoader loader;
    private AnchorPane layout;
    private Available_group_controller available_group_controller;
    private CheckBox enable_date_selection_check_box,start_date_check_box,end_date_check_box;
    private AnchorPane dates_container;
    private DatePicker start_date_Date_Picker,end_date_Date_Picker;
    private ChoiceBox<String> end_date;

    public void intiitalize(){
        try {
            loader=new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/Students/Available_group.fxml"));

            layout=loader.load();

            available_group_controller=loader.getController();

            enable_date_selection_check_box= (CheckBox) loader.getNamespace().get("check_add");

            dates_container=(AnchorPane)loader.getNamespace().get("dates_container");

            start_date_check_box=(CheckBox)loader.getNamespace().get("today_check_box");

            end_date_check_box=(CheckBox)loader.getNamespace().get("manual_check_box");

            start_date_Date_Picker=(DatePicker)loader.getNamespace().get("payment_date");

            end_date_Date_Picker=(DatePicker)loader.getNamespace().get("monthly_options_manual");

            end_date=(ChoiceBox<String>) loader.getNamespace().get("monthly_options");

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Available_group group, boolean b) {
        super.updateItem(group, b);
        if(group==null || b){
            setGraphic(null);
            setText(null);
        }
        else{
        intiitalize();

        available_group_controller.set_available_group(group.getTeacher_name(),group.getType(),group.getCount(),group.getSubject());


        if(group.isSelected()){ //verifying if the group was selected
            enable_date_selection_check_box.setSelected(true);
            dates_container.setDisable(false);
        }
        else{
            enable_date_selection_check_box.setSelected(false);
            dates_container.setDisable(true);
        }


 // a listener for the group selection check_box which enables the date container (the date container contains two date one for the start_date the other for the end_date , also one check_box for the start date implying that the start_date is today's date which is selected by default when it's not selected the user may input a date manually , the same goes for the end date except it's subscription based so i put a manual optino when the end_date box is selected and an automatic option (a choice box which has 1 month , 2 months ...etc) ).

       enable_date_selection_check_box.selectedProperty().addListener((observable,old_value,new_value)->{
            if(new_value){
                dates_container.setDisable(false);
                group.setSelected(true);
            }
            else{
                dates_container.setDisable(true);
                group.setSelected(false);
            }
        });



            if(!group.isStart_date_check()){
            start_date_check_box.setSelected(false);
            start_date_Date_Picker.setValue(group.getStart_date());
            start_date_Date_Picker.setDisable(false);
            }
            else{
                start_date_Date_Picker.setDisable(true);
                start_date_check_box.setSelected(true);
            }

  //this listener is for the start_date_check_box that switches between manual and automatic start_date selection
      start_date_check_box.selectedProperty().addListener((observableValue, old_value, new_value) -> {
            if(new_value){
                start_date_Date_Picker.setDisable(true);
                group.setStart_date_check(true);
                group.setStart_date(null);
            }
            else{
                start_date_Date_Picker.setDisable(false);
                group.setStart_date_check(false);
                start_date_Date_Picker.setValue(group.getStart_date());
                start_date_Date_Picker.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<LocalDate>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends LocalDate> observableValue, LocalDate localDate, LocalDate t1) {
                        group.setStart_date(t1);
                    }
                });
            }
        });


// this to ensure when the list refreshes the changes made to the layout stay. 

        if(group.isEnd_date_check()){
            end_date_Date_Picker.setVisible(true);
            end_date.setVisible(false);
            end_date_check_box.setSelected(true);
            end_date_Date_Picker.setValue(group.getEnd_date());
        }
        else{
            end_date_Date_Picker.setVisible(false);
            end_date.setVisible(true);
            end_date_check_box.setSelected(false);
            int index=0;
            if(group.getEnd_date().isAfter(LocalDate.now())){
                index=(group.getEnd_date().getMonthValue()-LocalDate.now().getMonthValue())-1;
            }
            end_date.getSelectionModel().select(index);
        }

 
  //this listener is for the end_date_check_box that switches between manual and automatic start_date selection

       end_date_check_box.selectedProperty().addListener(((observableValue, old_value, new_value) -> {
            if(new_value){
                group.setEnd_date(null);
                end_date_Date_Picker.setVisible(true);
                end_date.setVisible(false);
                group.setEnd_date_check(true);
                end_date_Date_Picker.setValue(null);
                end_date_Date_Picker.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<LocalDate>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends LocalDate> observableValue, LocalDate localDate, LocalDate t1) {
                        group.setEnd_date(t1);
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                group.setEnd_date(LocalDate.now().plusMonths(1));
                end_date_Date_Picker.setVisible(false);
                end_date.setVisible(true);
                group.setEnd_date_check(false);
                end_date.getSelectionModel().select(0);
                end_date_Date_Picker.setValue(group.getEnd_date());
            }

        }));


// this listener is for the automatic end_date_selection(the choice-box) which extends the end date based on the selected index +1 which means if the user puts the first option which is 1 month the selected index is 0 we then increment it by 1 which adds up to 1 that makes the end date  1 month from today's date

             end_date.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observableValue, old_value, new_value) -> {
                group.setEnd_date(LocalDate.now().plusMonths(end_date.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()+1));
            });


        setText(null);
        setGraphic(layout);
        }
    }
```

lastly this is the fxml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.CheckBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.DatePicker?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<AnchorPane maxHeight="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="202.0" prefWidth="579.0" styleClass="background" stylesheets="@Available_group.css" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/19" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Students.Available_group_controller">
   <children>
      <Label fx:id="teacher" alignment="CENTER" layoutY="72.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="579.0" styleClass="Label" text="Name" AnchorPane.topAnchor="72.0">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <ImageView fx:id="type_image" fitHeight="56.0" fitWidth="66.0" layoutX="34.0" layoutY="65.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="34.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="65.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../Groups/Groups_photos/special.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <Label fx:id="type" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="29.0" layoutY="29.0" prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="67.0" styleClass="Label" text="special" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="29.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="29.0" />
      <Label fx:id="count" alignment="CENTER" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="161.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="67.0" styleClass="Label" text="20/30" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.0">
         <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="18.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <CheckBox fx:id="check_add" layoutX="492.0" layoutY="75.0" mnemonicParsing="false" prefHeight="63.0" prefWidth="30.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="41.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="75.0">
         <font>
            <Font size="32.0" />
         </font>
      </CheckBox>
      <ImageView fx:id="subject" fitHeight="46.0" fitWidth="46.0" layoutX="267.0" layoutY="6.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" AnchorPane.topAnchor="6.0">
         <image>
            <Image url="@../Subjects/Subjects_photos/geography&amp;history.png" />
         </image>
      </ImageView>
      <AnchorPane fx:id="dates_container" disable="true" layoutX="168.0" layoutY="101.0" prefHeight="100.0" prefWidth="245.0">
         <children>
            <DatePicker fx:id="payment_date" disable="true" layoutY="24.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="167.0" promptText="Start_date" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="today_check_box" layoutX="179.0" layoutY="26.0" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" styleClass="Label" text="today" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </CheckBox>
            <CheckBox fx:id="manual_check_box" layoutX="178.0" layoutY="69.0" mnemonicParsing="false" styleClass="Label" text="manual" textFill="WHITE">
               <font>
                  <Font name="System Bold" size="15.0" />
               </font>
            </CheckBox>
            <StackPane layoutY="61.0" prefHeight="39.0" prefWidth="167.0">
               <children>
                  <DatePicker fx:id="monthly_options_manual" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="167.0" promptText="End_date" visible="false" />
                  <ChoiceBox fx:id="monthly_options" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="167.0" styleClass="Fields" />
               </children>
               <padding>
                  <Insets bottom="5.0" />
               </padding>
            </StackPane>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Thank you very much for your patience have a nice day.

Comment: At first glance, my guess is that you reloading the FXML for each `ListCell` each time `updateItem` is called is what's causing the flicker. This method is called when selection changes. BTW, your naming and general code styling is horrible to read. Please try and stick to the language conventions when you're publishing code.

Comment: @julien.giband hello and thank you for the criticism and the fast response , i tried to improve the readability i hope that now it's much clearer , and yes by flashing i meant flickering it's like the background goes transparent then comes back again when clicking on an item

Comment: try to add the initialize code to the default constructor and remove it from the update method

Comment: @Anon omg thank you XD i feel so dumb,  but then again i am still learning , thank you very much for the help

Answer (score 0):

As [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76586932/javafx-listview-selection#comment135033888_76586932) by @Anon, moving the initialize method to the default constructor fixes the flickering. The issue was that every time the list-view gets updated/refreshed by selecting an item the initialize method gets called, loading the layout again from scratch resulting in the flicker.